# Как скопировать базу SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте. Нужно скопировать небольшую базу на SQL Server с  одного компа на другой. 
Тыкните, пожалуйста, носом в инфу для чайников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Програмно или визуально? Визуально вот: [перенос файла БД Microsoft SQL на другой компьютер](http://sernam.ru/book_cbd.php?id=11).

Comment: Спасибо! Уже сделал через бэкап.

Answer (score 4):

1. В **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** нажимаем ПКМ на БД, которую будем переносить (*к примеру, 1C_BUH_test*), далее "Задачи" -> "Создать резервную копию" (настройки, оставляем по-умолчанию).
2. Переносим созданый *.bak файл резервной копии БД, на другой SQL-сервер.
3. В **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** нажимаем ПКМ на "Базы данных", далее "Восстановить базу данных".
4. Указываем перенесенный ранее, *.bak файл:
5. В выпадающем списке выбираем БД в которую будет производиться восстановление данных (*к примеру, 1C_BUH_test*).
6. Настройки сделаны нажимаем "ОК".
7. В случае успешного восстановления БД, будет уведомление.

   - Обязательно проверьте владельца БД после восстановления.
   - ПКМ на БД -> "Свойства" -> закладка "Файлы" -> поле "Владелец" (если оно пустое, то необходимо указать "Владельца" БД).
8. Указав "Владельца" БД нажимаем "ОК".

Ссылка на источник: [Описание процесса переноса через Backup](http://suntechnic.ru/index.php/library/instructions/1c-instructions/227-move-sql-v1.html)