# Как перенести базу данных созданную в Entity Framework на другой компьютер?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Как перенести базу данных созданную в Entity Framework на другой компьютер?
Работодатель должен проверить тестовое задание,не понимаю ,как передать ему бд.

Comment: Я добавил метку sql-server, так как у вас вероятнее всего вопрос про sql от майкрософт, но всё же лучше подтвердите, так это или нет.

Comment: Да,вы правы,используется Microsoft sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Базы, созданные в Entity Framework ничем не отличаются от обычных баз и неважно использовали ли вы Code First или Database Fisrt.

Самое простое и очевиденое - просто сделайте резервную копию (bak-файл) базы. Щёлкните правой кнопкой мыши по имени базы в SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio, ЕМНИП идёт в комплекте, но если нет - точно можно скачать бесплатно) и выберите пункт Tasks - Back Up.

Уверяю, вас на любой работе вполне поймут, если вы дадите bak-файл.

Чисто гипотетически, вы можете также выбрать пункт Tasks - Generate Scripts (главное: там на одном экране будет выбор, что экспортировать: данные или схему или "и данные и схему", по умолчанию там стоит "только схему") и вы сможете сгенерировать sql-скрипт (или набор sql-скриптов, по одному на таблицу), но этим обычно не пользуются.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Как скопировать базу SQL Server?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/108276/213987)